# Adding uploaded images from CMS to custom models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comfortable-mexican-sofa

I am using Comfortable Mexican Sofa and I want to create a few custom models. For instance, I would like to have a few *features*, each with a title, description and an icon.

So far I have followed instructions [here](https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa/wiki/Reusing-sofa%27s-admin-area). I have created a model and edited the generated form, but I haven't figured out a way to add existing, uploaded images to the model. I know I can add the panel with the uploaded files to the admin interface like this:

```
- content_for :right_column do
  = render :partial => 'comfy/admin/cms/files/index'
```

But I don't know how to use the images from this panel in my model. Is this possible to do without going trough and hacking the existing code? I know I can add an image field to my model using paperclip, but it seems like redundant work and it doesn't seem as user friendly -- ideally, I'd like to be able to simply drag and drop the image from the uploaded images panel to the field.

I have looked at the GitHub wiki, but it looks like the [entry about files](https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa/wiki/Files) has not been written yet.

Comment: If you want to create associations between your model and existing `Comfy::Cms::File` objects you'd need to create your own custom controls. If it's 1:1 relation you can just create something like `cms_file_id` and store against it. If you want one to many setup, you'll have to create a join table.

Comment: Yes I have done just that. Please submit this as your answer so that I can accept it.